# write a JavaScript function that returns a string that contains your name

Tags: javascript, function

So if my name is Ryan, I need to use a function to produce Ryan back to me.

In class, we did

```
function readnumber()
{
var s = readline();
return (s * 1);
}
```

We weren't taught anything else, so I'm really confused.

How about if I need to use a function to take a number and add 10 to it?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way for someone named *Ryan* is simply

```
function foo() {
    return "Ryan";
}
```

So you would then have

```
foo(); // "Ryan"
```

---

If you require some user interaction, then a simple modification of an example from [*Node.js's* documentation on `readline`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) gives you

```
var readline = require('readline'),
    rememberedName = null; // a variable to hold the name

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What is your name? ", function(answer) {
    console.log("Hello", answer); // great we now know the name
    rememberedName = answer; // store it so a function can return it
    rl.close();
});

// then after

function foo() { // a function which returns the name
    return rememberedName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhas something like this will help you:

```
function namePrompt()
  {
   var name = prompt("What's your name?"); 
   alert("Hello " + name);
  }
```

Th result will prompt the user for their name. After input, a dialog box will pop up saying "Hello " together with the user's name.

If you're using Node.js, change `alert` to `Console.log`.

Comment: I know the question isn't tagged as such, but I don't think _Node.js_ supports `alert`

Comment: I hate to do this to you a second time, but I think `prompt` also works a bit differently, too.. https://www.npmjs.org/package/prompt

Comment: @PaulS. I appreciate your comments. Unfortunately, I'm not so familiar with Node.js yet, so I'm not sure how to properly substitute prompt in Node.js. Also, the OP didn't specify, I didn't take it into consideration. Please edit the answer to add how to prompt in Node.js Thanks.